# Multi-threading in NLOPTR (The R package interface to NLOPT)

Tags: r, multithreading, nlopt

I'm trying to run a set of fairly large non-linear optimizations through an R interface.  (Yes, it must be R -- other languages don't work) I've been groveling around in the code, and I confess that I can't figure out whether NLOPT supports multithreaded operation, and, if so, how it gets kicked in.

Is it?

Comment: R does not support multithreaded operation. Is that  sufficient answer?

Comment: Well, no, it isn't.

First, although the R parse-eval loop contains a GKL and the garbage collector is essentially single threaded, there's a significant body of code which either uses OpenML or simple forking to create the illusion of multi-threaded support. More than that, though, there are packages like xgboost which use Posix threading under the hood directly, or use OpenBLAS under the hood like the Matrix package.

I'm asking whether nloptr and/or nlopt are of either form.

Comment: For really large sparse NLPs a solver like Ipopt (with R interface ipoptr) may be more appropriate than the solvers offered in nlopt/nloptr. Ipopt can be configured to use parallel linear algebra libraries such as Pardiso/MKL (most of the time is spent in those parts).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen  That looks perfect. My problem is a pure quadratic programming problem with linear equality and inequality constraints with very sparse Hessian matrices and trivially convex constraints, so interior point techniques may meet my needs, particularly since ipopt seems to support sparse matrices.